# Getting facebook mutual friends of some users (not my friends)

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get mutual friends count of users that aren't my friends.

This is the code (after auth.):

```
$fb_result = $facebook->api('/me/mutualfriends/'.$other_user_fb_id);
```

But when looping this code over 10-20 users it is too long\slow.

Is there any other method?

something like:

```
$fb_result = $facebook->api('/me/mutualfriends/'.user_fb_id1.','.user_fb_id2.','.....);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$fb_result = $facebook->api("/{$user_fb_id2}/mutualfriends/{$user_fb_id1}");
```

Note that, the user: `user_fb_id2` must be the user of your application for this to work.

UPDATE: You can use FQL Queries and Batch requests for this purpose.

Comment: me==user_fb_id2...this is not what I meant... I just want to loop on multiple users getting mutual friends of user_fb_id2 and user_fb_id(?), where (?) = 1...to...20. But when I am looping this is taking too long, is there any other fast method?